# Cross Validation: metrics to determine overfitting?

Tags: regression, classification, cross-validation

Let's say I'm doing a multivariate regression and I perform a k-fold cross validation. I'm aware of the CV error term, which is basically the average prediction error across every fold. My question is:

How do I take this error and determine if my model is overfit? Do I compare the CV error with the error of the model trained with the entire set? Is there some kind of threshold of error that hints to me an overfit?

And what about for classification problems? Do I simply take the percent of incorrect predictions and determine myself whether or not such error is acceptable?

Just not sure if there's a proper way of evaluating a cross-validation result to determine if my model is an overfit.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Big training errors and big validation errors can indicate underfitting.  Small training errors and big validation errors can indicate overfitting.  Cross-validation can be used as a method of tuning hyperparameters in your model so as to try to minimise the risk of both (for example how many of the independent variables are worth using in your multivariate regression)

Comment: It's called regularization.  As a first, look at ridge regression.